# Browser compatibility issue: layout not working in Firefox

Tags: html, css, browser, opacity

I am having browser issues, and even issues using the same browser on a different PC.

My links are not in position over the background. Using Firefox, the opacity isn't working, or the positioning.

You can see the site here [www.haelu.co.nf](http://www.haelu.co.nf/)

HTML:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<title>Haelu</title>
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="mystyle.css">
</head>

<body>



<a id="button1" href="https://soundcloud.com/haelu">
<img src="images/Button1.png" border="0"></a> 

<a id="button2" href="/videos.html">
<img border="0" src="images/Button2.png" ></a>

</body>

</html>
```

External CSS:

```
html { 
    background: url(images/WebBack1.jpg) no-repeat center center fixed; 
    -webkit-background-size: cover;
    -moz-background-size: cover;
    -o-background-size: cover;
    background-size: cover;
}

@font-face {
    font-family: webfont;
    src: url(thinnyness.ttf);
    src: local('Delicious'), local(Delicious'),
    url(thinnyness.ttf) format('truetype');
}

body {
    font-family:Webfont;
    align: center;
}

#button1 { 
    position: absolute; 
    top: 364px; 
    left: 557px; 
    opacity:0.1;
}

#button1:hover {
    position: absolute; 
    top: 364px; 
    left: 557px; 
    opacity:1.0;
}

#button2 { 
    position: absolute; 
    top: 292px; 
    left: 648px; 
    opacity:0.1;
}   

#button2:hover {
    position: absolute; 
    top: 292px; 
    left: 648px; 
    opacity:1.0;
}

.center {
    margin: 0 auto;
    width: 500px;
}

#container {
   position: absolute;
   top: 50%;
   margin-top: -130px;/* half of #content height*/
   left: 0;
   width: 100%;
}
```

Comment: Lookls like you have some font-face definition messed up. look for 'bulletproof font-face syntax' in google.

Comment: there is no problem with the font. it works, but i am aware it's a mess

Comment: The problem is the links. their position is not consistent on different browsers and pc's, and on firefox their opacity isn't working and they are in the top left screen

Comment: sorry you are right. the font isn't working either with firefox. and my video is also incorrectly positioned in firefox :(

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I believe your problem is the syntax error in your CSS:

```
@font-face {
    font-family: webfont;
    src: url(thinnyness.ttf);
    src: local('Delicious'), local(Delicious'),
    url(thinnyness.ttf) format('truetype');
}
```

You're missing the leading apostrophe in the second `local(Delicious')` declaration. This is causing the whole stylesheet to break, preventing the positioning from working.